# Howto map a given external type with Openapi codegen into a generated model class

Tags: java, jax-rs, openapi, openapi-generator, openapi-generator-maven-plugin

I'm using Openapi 3.0.3 with openapi-generator-maven-plugin 6.6.0 and the jaxrs-spec generator.

I have to map a given type external to the API from a given external library in my schema definition, I tried with `x-implements` like:

```
myExternalTypeToMap:
    x-implements: 'path.to.external.type.that.should.be.mapped.MyExternalTypeToMap'
    x-field-extra-annotation: '@JsonIgnore'
```

but that gets mapped into the generated model class like this:

```
@JsonIgnore
private @Valid Object myExternalTypeToMap = null;
```

How can I get a mapping to:

```
@JsonIgnore
private @Valid path.to.external.type.that.should.be.mapped.MyExternalTypeToMap myExternalTypeToMap;
```

in my generated model class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it kinda works with in the pom.xml

```
<typeMappings>
    <typeMapping>MyExternalTypeToMap=path.to.external.type.that.should.be.mapped.MyExternalTypeToMap</typeMapping>
</typeMappings>
```

and in the schema yaml

```
myExternalTypeToMap:
  x-field-extra-annotation: '@JsonIgnore'
  type: MyExternalTypeToMap
```

what compiles to

```
@JsonIgnore
private @Valid path.to.external.type.that.should.be.mapped.MyExternalTypeToMap myExternalTypeToMap = null;
```

what is good enough for the moment. Would like to get rid of the null initialization though.